# How to diagonalize a matrix when it has more eigenvectors than eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve this problem:

Give an example of a matrix A with the following three properties:

1. A has eigenvalues −1 and 2.
2. The eigenvalue −1 has eigenvector (1,2,3).
3. The eigenvalue 2 has eigenvectors (1,1,0) and (0,1,1).

I tried solving it using
 $$A= PDP^{-1}$$
But D is 2x2 and P is 3x3 so multiplication is not possible. How do we deal with cases like this when a matrix has more eigenvectors than eigenvalues?

Comment: How did you deduce that $A$ is a $2×2$ matrix? It can sure have repeated eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each eigenvalue appears once in $D$ for each eigenvector it has in your collection of eigenvectors. So in this case, $D$ has $2$ twice along the diagonal. A few requirements, though:

- The collection of eigenvectors for any given eigenvalue must be linearly independent
- There must still be a full set of eigenvectors, which is to say there must be $n$ of them for an $n\times n$ matrix

As long as these are fulfilled, the are no issues.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have three linearly independent eigenvectors the diagonalization is possible. The matrix $P$ whose columns are the eigenvectors serves as the engine in the process of $$P^{-1}AP=D$$

The matrix $A$

is found by solving the equations $$AV=\lambda V$$ for given eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

My calculation resulted in $$A=\begin {bmatrix}1/2&3/2&-3/2\\-3&5&-3\\-9/2&9/2&-5/2\end{bmatrix}$$